# How to get a word or a piece of text -- in Android/JAVA

Tags: java, android, text, line

How to get a word or a piece of text from a specific column in a specific row.

For example, in the text below we have 4 lines:

---

"Era uma casa

muito engraçada

não tinha teto

não tinha nada."

---

How do I get in the first row, the word that comes from the ninth column, that is, the word "casa"?

In the second line the word that comes from the seventh column, that is, the word "engraçada"

In the third line I don't want to take anything

And in the fourth line, take the entire text of the line

I did not put any code, because I have no idea how to start, if someone can help me I will be grateful.

P.S: Remembering that it will not always be the same text

Comment: How do you store this text? Is it a String? If so, I suggest you look at the Java API docs for String to see if there are any useful methods to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string.split("\n") and you will have a array of lines, after that you can do this action for every array item(line) to solve the problem